# Adding a ActivityIndicator to UIView

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiactivityindicatorview

I need to add an `activityIndicator` to a UIView.I have a button,when that button is clicked then it has to start animating. Actually when the button is clicked some data is received from rest service and parsing is done and then it is filled in `UITableView`.But the activity indicator is not getting animating..

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

  UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] 
                                                  initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 20.0f, 20.0f)];
    [activityIndicator setActivityIndicatorViewStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];

    [self.view addSubview:activityIndicator];
}
-(IBAction)switchtoGetProviders
{
   [activityIndicator startAnimating];
 NSURL *urlString= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://230.32.232.32/services/service.svc/Xml"];  
        NSMutableURLRequest *request=[[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init]autorelease];
..............//calling data from service url 

}
```

After reciving the whole data it is assigned to `UITableView`.

How can I get it working ?

Comment: sorry i was editing so i am late to reply..but the solution is you are not doing [activityIndicator startAnimating];

Comment: is your problem is not with activity indicator frame????

Comment: helloo i am asking to u..??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably this is due to the fact that you are making the webservice call and updating the UI at the same time on MAIN Thread. You must use GCD or detach another thread for making the webservice call.

Use this to detach a new thread

```
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(callWebserviceMethod:) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
```

In your code

```
-(IBAction)switchtoGetProviders
{
    [activityIndicator startAnimating];
     [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(callWebserviceMethod:) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
}

-(void)callWebserviceMethod
{

    NSURL *urlString= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://230.32.232.32/services/service.svc/Xml"];  
    NSMutableURLRequest *request=[[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init]autorelease];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't start and stop activity indicator in one single function/method.

There are two methods to do this things.

If the request is Asynchronous then you need to start activity indicator at button click and stop when you receive response.

But if the request is synchronous then it is not possible to start and stop activity in one function.for this you need to start animation on button click and make separate method for send synchronous request and call that method using [self performSelector:] method. At the end you need to stop animating.

Updates:

```
-(IBAction)switchtoGetProviders
{
   [activityIndicator startAnimating];
   [self performSelector:@selector(startRequest) withObject:nil afterDelay:0];
}
- (void)startRequest 
{
   NSURL *urlString= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://230.32.232.32/services/service.svc/Xml"];  
        NSMutableURLRequest *request=[[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init]autorelease];
..............//calling data from service url 

  [activityIndicator stopAnimating];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should define activityIndicator as a property, in your code you have it as a local variable. 
After defining it as a property, change the assignment line to:

```
self.activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 20.0f, 20.0f)];
```

Comment: If your request is synchronous then well, you can't do this because the gui will not get refreshed. Use an asynchronous request as others have suggested.

Answer (score 0):

just add this line in .h file

```
UIActivityIndicatorView *spinningWheel;
```

and in `viewWillAppear` method add this code..

```
    spinningWheel = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(120, 200, 25.0, 25.0)];

    spinningWheel.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge;///UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray also use this if background white
    [self.view addSubview:spinningWheel];


-(IBAction)switchtoGetProviders
{
   [spinningWheel startAnimating];
 NSURL *urlString= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://230.32.232.32/services/service.svc/Xml"];  
        NSMutableURLRequest *request=[[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init]autorelease];
..............//calling data from service url 

}
```

and when you get data or response at that time stopAnimating like bellow..

```
   [spinningWheel stopAnimating];
```

Comment: Actually I m posting synchronous XML request to service url and receiving response.I didn't use any such fnc of this kind im my app - (void) connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)theConnection {

Comment: oh then somewhere you got the data and get response on it right?? then  at that time stopAnimating speeningWheel dude...

Comment: leave abt stop animation .but atleast it should start animation no when I click on button

Comment: hey i edit code now and replace with it i change the frame CGPoint and also try to change indicatorStyle.. if your background white then use gray indecator try the code dude.. :) i hope this help you...

Comment: -(IBAction)switchtoGetProviders
{
   [spinningWheel startAnimating];            [self.view bringSubviewToFront:spinningWheel];} also add as a suerview this speeningWheel dude...

Answer (score 0):

you need to get data from web service in background thread, as calling it on the main thread causes the UI to hang

[see this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html)

Answer (score 0):

You have declared the UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator in viewDidLoad method so it is local object only visible to this function you need to declare it in the header file or in class category in .m. When you declare the activityIndicator instance in the .h then you will be able to access this within your class. Either you can make it as property or just declare in .h then initialize in your viewDidLoad method without redeclaration.

Comment: I have declared it in .h file as u have said like this IBOutlet UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator;.but still didn't get it working

Comment: what issue you are facing with?

Comment: activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped=YES;

When you done with your rest services then call.
[activityIndicator stopAnimating];

Comment: I cannot see the activity indicator starting animation at all when button is clicked..

Comment: try with different frame and different activity indicator style.    set a breakpoint when your start animating activity indicator that it is properly initialized?

Answer (score 0):

Just do one this , declare it in .h file mean declare glibly

**.h**

```
@interface yourViewController : UIViewController
{
    IBOutlet UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator;
}
```

**.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(143, 220, 37, 37)];
    activityIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge;
    activityIndicator.color = [UIColor blackColor];
    [self.view addSubview:activityIndicator];
}  


-(IBAction)switchtoGetProviders
{
   [activityIndicator startAnimating];

 NSURL *urlString= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://230.32.232.32/services/service.svc/Xml"];  
        NSMutableURLRequest *request=[[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init]autorelease];
..............//calling data from service url 

}
```

Comment: Your have activity indicator and it is animating but at top left of view...and may be its color is same as view color...

Comment: but I need it when I click a button.When I add the same code in button click it is not working..

Comment: it on button click do startAnimating

Comment: No the prob is not with frame.As u have said if i set my frame eventhough it doesn't start animating on button click

Comment: no brother just add activityIndicator and set its frame to middle of view...then initially hide your activityIndicator and on button click unhide your activityIndicator and startanimating... this is simple solution...if you are not understanding then just make IBOUTLET and and add activityIndicator from xib and connect,....try this